# What is address(1) in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Recently, i read smart contracts of compound finance.
In PriceOracleProxy.sol(https://etherscan.io/address/0xe7664229833AE4Abf4E269b8F23a86B657E2338D#code)

line  3863 shows:

address constant usdcOracleKey = address(1);
i'm confusing of this address(1), what's meaning of it.

```
/**
 * @notice address of the cUSDC contract, which we hand pick a key for
 */
address public cUsdcAddress;

/**
 * @notice address of the USDC contract, which we hand pick a key for
 */
address constant usdcOracleKey = address(1);


last used:
     return v1PriceOracle.assetPrices(usdcOracleKey);
```

Answer (score 3):

Its just another way to write `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001`,
by the same logic address(0) is `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`